# Need help stripping off characters using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a string: `abc-2.25_20141104-1586.uvw.xyz`

I'd like to strip off `.uvw.xyz` and retain `abc-2.25_20141104-1586`. How can I do that using `sed`? Help appreciated!

Comment: Can there be number in the two last fields, or more/less characters than `3`, like this: `abc-2.25_20141104-1586.uvsw.xyz` or `abc-2.25_20141104-1586.uv3.xyz`?  Do you like to remove last two fields regardless of what they contains?

Comment: I realized there could be more than 3 characters in the last 2 fields in some cases. I was able account for that by adapting some of the solutions posted here. Sure, the ideal solution, removes the last 2 fields regardless of what it contains, but I have what I need for the time being.

Comment: Then you should review what solution is the best for you.  What is the rule to get what you want. What can last field contain? digits, letters how many.  How many last field do you like to remove? Always two?  Doing some programming I often see large pitfall and that tings go wrong to not testing everything with sufficient input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "abc-2.25_20141104-1586.uvw.xyz" | sed 's/\.[a-z]\{3\}\.[a-z]\{3\}//g'
```

**output**

```
abc-2.25_20141104-1586
```

Comment: This will fail of one of the two last fields contains more or less than 3 characters or it contains numbers. `abc-2.25_20141104-1586.uvsw.xyz` or `abc-2.25_20141104-1586.uv3.xyz` will both fail.

Comment: @Jotne it will also fail if there'll be digits instead of letters as well as many other scenarios. This solution handles only the case specified by the OP, to handle other (more general) cases the regex will obviously have to change.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "abc-2.25_20141104-1586.uvw.xyz" | sed 's/\(.*-[0-9]*\)\..*/\1/'
abc-2.25_20141104-1586
```

Explanation: (.*-[0-9]*)=> Matches everything else in the beginning except the suffix you do not want.
And
1 => Is the first pattern matched.

Please see:
http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51
(Section on keeping the pattern)

Comment: This will fail it there are letters after the first `.` like this: `abc-2.25_20141104-1586A.uvwmore.xyzyes`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "abc-2.25_20141104-1586.uvw.xyz" | sed 's/.uvw.xyz$//'

Output: 
abc-2.25_20141104-1586
```

Comment: `.uvw.xyz` are placeholders for **any** characters, not specifically `u`, `v`,`w`,....

Comment: He didn't say that in the OP - it *could* mean that - yet the way it is worded I interpret the OP as meaning literal or hardcoded stripping of a filename extension. Plus file name extensions aren't something you normally see having a plethora of different types (though its possible).

Comment: That's why your answer didn't get a downvote. However, generally speaking, and specifically, from the context of the question, it was clear they were generic characters. Always try to provide the most general solution as an answer.

Comment: He didn't say that in his OP - unless you ask him specifically I don't see how you can intuit his intention. He stated uvw.xyz, there could be any number of reasons someone may genericize file extensions or other data in a question on a public forum - including yet not limited to security issues - yet still have the intent of asking about a specific file extension.

Comment: David, thanks for your feedback. I'll try to be more specific in the future. But A.Danischewski assumed correctly that I was looking to manipulate the filename with a specific extension without being very specific about what the extension was. Thanks for the simple solution.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification testphreak - though I'm not sure why you chose the semi-generic answer for this it will strip other things out of the middle of the file name for cases like this:    abc-2.254.20141.fgg.jhf104-1586.uvw.xyz   - Mine too has a problem because I didn't put an anchor on so I have fixed mine as well. Many of these answers if you want generic should probably include an more extensive character list and be anchored to the end $.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility:

```
sed 's/\.[[:alpha:]]\{3\}\>//g'
```

Explanation: Start at `.`, followed by three alphabetic characters, followed by end of word.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use sed. Can be accomplished fairly easily with the basename command:

```
basename abc-2.25_20141104-1586.uvw.xyz .uvw.xyz
```

Should output

```
abc-2.25_20141104-1586
```

Comment: `.uvw.xyz` are placeholders for **any** characters, not specifically `u`, `v`,`w`,....

Answer (score 0):

using awk:

```
echo "abc-2.25_20141104-1586.uvw.xyz" | awk '{gsub('/\.uvw\.xyz/',"",$0); print $0}'
```

other approach:

```
a="abc-2.25_20141104-1586.uvw.xyz"
echo ${a%.uvw.xyz}
```

output:

```
abc-2.25_20141104-1586
```

Comment: `.uvw.xyz` are placeholders for **any** characters, not specifically `u`, `v`,`w`,.... Perhaps `echo ${a%.*.*}`

Answer (score 0):

if you just know that you will always want to remove last two placeholders separated by dots:

```
$ string="abc-2.25_20141104-1586.uvw.xyz" 
$ string=${string%.*}
$ echo ${string%.*}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` way to do it.  (It will remove any length of last w fields)

```
echo "abc-2.25_20141104-1586.uvwmore.xyzyes" | awk -F\. 'NF-=2' OFS=\.
abc-2.25_20141104-1586
```